# Mysql utf-8 behaves differently into different environments

Tags: mysql, character-set

I have MySQL server under docker in 2 different environments:

This is my create database:

```
CREATE DATABASE guests CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI;
```

This is the create table:

```
USE guests;
CREATE TABLE MyGuests ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

This is how I Insert data:

```
insert into MyGuests (firstName)  VALUES("בדיקה");
insert into MyGuests (firstName)  VALUES("ة التي تح");
insert into MyGuests (firstName)  VALUES("7");
```

In the one environment, I get question marks in the result.
In the other environment, I get the correct characters

[image]

The good environment is mysql in a docker under windows 10.
The bad one is mysql in a docker under Ubuntu.

This is the result for running:

This is the output of the command `mysql> show variables like '%collation%';` in the **bad** env.

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

This is the output of the command `mysql> show variables like '%collation%';` in the **good** env.

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_bin        |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+----------------------+-------------------=+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had missing in the connection string `CharSet=utf8mb4` in the bad env

`Server=10.5.0.5;Database=db;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=root;CharSet=utf8mb4`